# std::function method reference unable to cast DWORD to DWORD64?

Tags: c++, winapi, functional-programming

I am having trouble referencing a member function of my `MyClass` class. Please, consider this abstraction as my problem.

```
class MyClass {
   public:

   DWORD fun_32(_In_ DWORD64 a64bitparam); //wants DWORD64 returns DWORD
   DWORD64 fun_64(_In_ DWORD64 a64bitparam); //wants DWORD64 returns DWORD64

   DWORD64 fun(_In_ DWORD64 a64bitparam);

   private:
   BOOLEAN use64;
};
```

An `fun(DWORD64)` implementation:

```
DWORD64 MyClass::fun(DWORD64 a64bitparam) {

   std::function<DWORD64(DWORD64)> myReference;
   myReference = this->use64 ? &MyClass::fun_64 : &MyClass::fun_32;

}
```

The example won't compile as 'operand types are incompatible'. Somehow the program is not able to cast `DWORD` to an `DWORD64`.

However, this one does, but looks ugly. (IMO)

```
std::function<DWORD64(DWORD64)> myReference;
myReference = [this](DWORD64 a) -> DWORD64 { return use64 ? fun_64(a) : fun_32(a);};
```

Could someone briefly explain me what I am doing wrong with the method reference?

Comment: Member functions require a object to call them on.  You either need to make the static to get around this or use a lambda or `std::bind` to bind a object to the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver: answer section...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I figured there was a dupe so I commented and then went dupe hunting

Comment: Standard response about not providing an answer at all if you think there's a dupe, let alone doing so in the wrong place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The example won't compile as 'operand types are incompatible'. Somehow the program is not able to cast DWORD to an DWORD64.

No, that is not what is going on.

The problem is that you are trying to take the address of a member function, then shove it in a type that doesn't expect a pointer-to-member-function.

Pointers-to-member-functions are strange beasts, due to the need to bind a `this` pointer when you invoke them. In your attempt, invoking `myReference()` (if it were possible) would not make any sense. Which `MyClass` object would it be invoked on?

You'd be better off using a lambda (as you already showed), or `std::bind` if you must.

Alternatively, consider whether those functions actually require object state; if not, they could be `static` (and then they are basically the same as non-member functions, for our purposes here).

Comment: Thank you very much for depth explaination. The methods fun_64 and fun_32 are required to be member functions, so I guess I'll stick with the lambdas.

Comment: @glf4k: Have you considered just calling the functions directly? I don't really understand why you need the roundtrip through `std::function`, but I guess we can't see all of your code.

Comment: Yes I have considered, making if statements for each case (32 or 64) makes the code more unreadable. There is pretty long code going directly after the myReference declaration :}

Comment: @glf4k There's only one point of branching, though? `if (use64) return fun_64(a); else return fun_32(a);` or, if you need the value later, `const DWORD64 val = (use64 ? fun_64(a) : fun_32(a));`. Struggling to see how much more complex it can be unless even the `std::function` solution is not quite as shown here

Comment: I've invoking the myReference function for different 'a' parameters (DWORD64) in the function. the first one (which comes from fun method argument is just an first step. I'll think about it now when its more clear to me. Please, dont waste your time and consider my question as very well answered :)

Comment: @glf4k: Okay, then that makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: @glf4k: Actually one final note, if the function is staying local, then write `auto myReference = [=](...) { ... };'` instead of storing it in a `std::function<>` — it'll be as performant as if the code were inline.

Comment: "*you are trying to take the address of a member function, then shove it in a type that doesn't expect a pointer-to-member-function*" - `std::function` does support pointer-to-member-functions in general, eg: `std::function<DWORD64(const MyClass&,DWORD64)> myReference; myReference = &MyClass::fun_64; myReference(SomeMyClassObj, 12345);` Or: `std::function<DWORD64(DWORD64)> myReference; myReference = std::bind(&MyClass::fun_64, SomeMyClassObj, std::placeholders::_1); myReference(12345);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Right, so now you're using a type that _does_ expect a pointer-to-member-function (or, okay, more strictly is compatible with one). Interesting approach, though. The solution with `bind` I already mentioned.